# Is it possible to use the vacuum of space to help with pollution

Tags: space

Would it be possible to use a pipeline from the ground and uses the vacuum of space to dispose of things that are hazardous to the environment? (Liquid waste in particular comes to mind) Essentially acting as a syphon that shoots the waste off into the universe?

Comment: No, no, no, no, no. I had to repeat myself because a comment has to be at least 15 characters long.

Comment: I commend the originality of your idea.

Comment: We are already polluting the Earth, why do you want to go ahead and pollute space?

Comment: No. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69806/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/207076/123208 & the other questions linked there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about building a space elevator, not about astronomy

Comment: **The answer: what causes air to remain on the Earth? The same causes that nothing will go into the space through such a syphon.**

Answer (score 7):

No.

It is hard to get stuff into space.  If you built a pipe that went to space, it wouldn't suck stuff up for the same reason that the atmosphere doesn't get sucked off the Earth: Gravity pulls things down.  Instead you would have to pump stuff up the pipe, you would need lots of power to do this.  And when it reaches the top it would just fall down, unless you make your pipe 36000km long, so that the rotation of the Earth becomes strong enough to push it away

What you have essentially built is a space elevator. There are huge engineering challenges in making a space elevator.  It is honestly the very hardest way to get rid of pollution.